# What is the purpose of making Editable as return type of EditText.getText() method?

Tags: java, android

As per the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29), the `getText()` method of `EditText` returns `Editable`. What was the purpose of it? It could simply have been a `String` return type?

And as per the `Editable` [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html):

> This is the interface for text whose content and markup can be changed (as opposed to immutable text like Strings).

To achieve immutable functionality, why not use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public interface Editable implements GetChars, Spannable, Appendable, CharSequence
```

Amoung other features, Editable retains Spannable data which Strings and StringBuilders cannot do.